# Twisted: how to know when all the data has been received?

Tags: python, twisted

```
self.agent = Agent(reactor, pool=pool)
self.deferred = self.agent.request(
            'GET',
            self.url,
            Headers({'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0']})
        )

self.deferred.addCallback(self.gotResponse)
```

But gotResponse called for every part of received data, not for all of it. I could collect it, but how to know that i got all the data?

**EDIT:**

I found [this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) (from the words "*If the response body has been completely received*") but still have no idea how to implement this. I mean, what does *"the failure will wrap..."* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twisted documentation provides an example of how to do this.

From http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

```
from pprint import pformat

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.remaining = 1024 * 10

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print 'Some data received:'
            print display
            self.remaining -= len(display)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        self.finished.callback(None)

agent = Agent(reactor)
d = agent.request(
    'GET',
    'http://example.com/',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
    None)

def cbRequest(response):
    print 'Response version:', response.version
    print 'Response code:', response.code
    print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
    print 'Response headers:'
    print pformat(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(BeginningPrinter(finished))
    return finished
d.addCallback(cbRequest)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

The connectionLost() method of BeginningPrinter will be called when the request has completed.

```
Response version: ('HTTP', 1, 0)
Response code: 302
Response phrase: Found
Response headers:
[('Location', ['http://www.iana.org/domains/example/']), ('Server', ['BigIP'])]
Finished receiving body: Response body fully received
```

It looks like checking `if reason.check(twisted.web.client.ResponseDone)` will tell you whether or not it was successful.

Comment: You should use `reason.check(someType)` instead of `reason.type == someType`.  The former respects inheritance hierarchies in the same way the `except` statement does.  Also, the proper name for `ResponseDone` is `twisted.web.client.ResponseDone`, not `twisted.web._newclient.ResponseDone`.  In general, names that have a component that begins with `_` are private and applications should not use them.

Comment: Good catch, I totally missed the underscore.

Answer (score 3):

In twisted 13.1.0 you can use readBody(). From
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.readBody.html, "This is a helper function for clients that don't want to incrementally receive the body of an HTTP response."

You call readBody() from your callback, dataReceived() in the example above, which handles the data, readBody() returns a deferred to which you attach another callback which gets the whole body as parameter.

HTH,
Reshad.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not knowledgeable with twisted enough to give you a proper answer ...  but i can point in some good directions.

with twisted deferreds you create a chain of callbacks (success) and errbacks (fails) that trigger when something completes.

in your example - i'm not sure what self.agent.request does , or why it could be returning parts of data.  that doesn't sound entirely 'right' to me -- but usually i fetch urls with blocking code that is wrapped within a deferred SemaphoreService.

but, based on your code, i want to suggest two things:

a - read up on deferreds here http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html

b - you'll want to add an errback to handle the bad requests.  the text about "wrapping" has to deal with the fact that twisted doesn't really raise an error -- instead it lets you define errBacks to run , and you can trap an error in those.  someone better with twisted can hopefully explain this a bit more properly - but because deferreds are asynchronous, you need a mechanism like this to effectively handle errors.

```
class YourExample(object):
    def your_example(self):
        self.agent = Agent(reactor, pool=pool)
        self.deferred = self.agent.request(
                'GET',
                self.url,
                Headers({'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0']})
            )

        self.deferred.addCallback(self.gotResponse).addErrback(self.gotBadResponse)

def gotBadResponse(self,raised):
    """you might have cleanup code here, or mark the url as bad in the database, or something similar"""
    pass
```